# Cucumber -Run scenario only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am looking for a solution for the following scenario.
I am writing the cucumber-capybara tests for the Ruby on Rails application.

I have multiple cucumber feature file with several scenarios (say Scenario B...Z) which are dependent on one particular scenario (say Scenario A). I want to run the scenario only once for all the scenarios which are dependent on it.
So if i run the scenarios (B....Z)  I wanted to run the dependent scenario (A) only once. I came across Before hook in cucumber but it will run once for every scenario.

I have one feature file and in that there is one scenario which provisions a server. (Scenario A)

I have multiple other feature files and multiple scenarios (Scenario B..Z) which will run the tests assuming that the server is actually provisioned (Scenario A)

So whenever someone runs the dependent scenarios (Scenario B..Z ), it should check if server is provisioned by some other scenario then it should not try to provision the server. As it will increase the no.of servers.

Comment: So, based on my comment bellow, You can add a check to see if server is provisioned in your `Given` block. If yes, do nothing, else: provision a server

Answer (score 0):

You could write a feature with scenario A, and then write a `Given` block which will set the initial expectation for what scenario A is about, Then you can call that before scenario B..Z

So, assuming scenario A is to sign in, then write a single feature for signing in, and then for scenario B to Z, you write a given block that set a user as signed-in, and use that as:

```
Given user is signed in
...
```

where `Given user is signed in` is defined like:

```
Given /^user is signed in$/ do
  # code to sign a user in
end
```

Comment: Added more information to the question. 
By referring to your example , if I wanted to check that user should log in only once even if the "Given user is signed in" is called from multiple feature files , how can I do that ?

Comment: You can add a check in the `Given user is signed in` block, to see if there is a user signed in. If yes, do nothing, else, sign in user

Comment: I have moved the step definition file inside the support directory and the following if block gets executed always

$dunit ||= true  value
  if $dunit then 
  puts "Hey I am runnig now "
  $dunit = false
  end           

For each scenario in different files I always see "Hey I am runnig now " printed on console

Comment: This is the complete code I am trying 
Before('@dependent') do

$dunit ||= true 


 if $dunit then puts "Hey I am runnig now " $dunit = false end 

end

Comment: Yes now, you are doing `$dunit ||= true`. this will always make sure `$dunit` is `true`